# Convert spaces to tabs in RegEx

Tags: regex, string

How do do you say the following in regex:

```
foreach line
   look at the beginning of the string and convert every group of 3 spaces to a tab
   Stop once a character other than a space is found
```

This is what i have so far:

```
/^ +/\t/g
```

However, this converts every space to 1 tab

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write for code for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Perl:

```
perl -pe '1 while s/\G {3}/\t/gc' input.txt >output.txt
```

For example, with the following input

```
nada
   three spaces
    four spaces
   three   in the middle
      six space
```

the output (TABs replaced by `\t`) is

```
$ perl -pe '1 while s/\G {3}/\t/gc' input | perl -pe 's/\t/\\t/g'
nada
\tthree spaces
\t four spaces
\tthree   in the middle
\t\tsix spaces
```

Comment: Greg, thanks for the great answer!  It seems to be unnecessarily complicated, however.   Both the `1 while` and the `//c` seem superfluous.  Just to be sure, I tried running your sample input with all permutations of keeping/omitting those two superfluous items and got identical output.  So, one could simplify the code by just having `perl -pe 's/\G {3}/\t/g'`

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but I thought I'd give a full regex answer that works (well it worked for me).

```
s/^\t* {3}/\t/g
```

Comment: Converts spaces in the middle of the line, violating "Stop once a character other than a space is found"

Answer (score -1):

You probably want `/^(?: {3})*/\t/g`

edit: fixed

Comment: This converts 3 spaces to 1 tab - but also 6 or 9 or 12 etc. spaces to only 1 tab.

Comment: not fixed.  Try running it on Greg Bacon's sample data.  "nada" and "six spaces" are both broken.  And it's missing the leading `s`.