# How can I repeat a Perl Regular Expression until no changes are left?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to write a simple command line script to fix some whitespace and need to replace occurrences of two spaces with a tab, but only if it appears at the beginning of the line (prefixed only by other tabs.)

I came up with `s/^(\t*)  /\1\t/g;` which works perfectly if I run through multiple passes, but I don't know enough about perl to know how to loop until the string didn't change, or if there is a regular expression way to handle it.

My only thought was to use a lookbehind but it can't be variable length.  I'd be open to a non-regex solution if its short enough to fit into a quick command line script.

For reference, the current perl script is being executed like so:

```
perl -pe 's/^(\t*)  /$1\t/g'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854152/convert-spaces-to-tabs-in-regex).

You could use `1 while s/^(\t*)  /$1\t/g;` to repeat the pattern until there are no changes left to make.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I went ahead and added the solution your post.

Comment: `\1` (a pattern that means "match what's in `$1`") is wrong in replacement expression. Should be `$1`.

Comment: oh well I just pointed out a similar question. You're right tho.

Comment: @ikegami thats for the additional info - I edited his post to reflect those notes...

Comment: Hi, sysfault. Can you explain it further? `1 while` seems quite odd to me? Why it does the job?

Comment: @user15964 `1 while` is like saying "return 1 (i.e., do nothing) while `s/.../` returns true (while it matches.)  You can see an example in `man perlop` by searching for "Occasionally, you can't use just a"

Comment: If you write a script, it's better to write `do {} while ...` instead of `1 while ...` even though both result in identical behavior. Another alternative is `true while ...` but I think explicit do-while syntax is easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

or

```
perl -pe 's{^(\t*)((  )+)}{$1 . "\t" x (length($2)/length($3))}e'
```

Answer (score 1):

Supports mixes of spaces and tabs:

```
perl -pe'($i,$s)=/^([ \t]*)([.*])/s; $i=~s/  /\t/g; $_="$i$s";'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Perl, so you don't have to do a loop. Instead you could just evaluate in the replace expression, like so:

```
my $tl = 4;
s{ ( \t* ) ( [ ]* ) }
 { my $l=length( $2 ); 
   "$1" . ( "\t" x int( $l / $tl )) . ( ' ' x ( $l % $tl ))
 }ex
;
```

Comment: @Bill Ruppert This is *basically* a one-liner. The `$tl` simply shows how the number of spaces per tab works.